# PHP: 2 strings - which one is UTF-8 and which one not?

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a database with lots of strings. Some of them are correctly UTF-8 encoded, some of them not. Therefore, I've set up a script which selects 100 strings from the db. The following function decides whether a string contains UTF-8 or not (no matter if it's correct):

```
function detectUTF8($text) {
    return preg_match('%(?:
        [\xC2-\xDF][\x80-\xBF]             # non-overlong 2-byte
        |\xE0[\xA0-\xBF][\x80-\xBF]        # excluding overlongs
        |[\xE1-\xEC\xEE\xEF][\x80-\xBF]{2} # straight 3-byte
        |\xED[\x80-\x9F][\x80-\xBF]        # excluding surrogates
        |\xF0[\x90-\xBF][\x80-\xBF]{2}     # planes 1-3
        |[\xF1-\xF3][\x80-\xBF]{3}         # planes 4-15
        |\xF4[\x80-\x8F][\x80-\xBF]{2}     # plane 16
        )+%xs',
    $text);
}
```

[The output of of script is these strings containing UTF-8 and - after a line break - the utf8_decode() string. Since some strings are double encoded, I decode all strings which you can see there.](http://www.twem.de/18.php)

The result is a list with some entries with 2 strings each: one is correct, the other one is wrong. You can see it here. But how do I determine which one is correct?

I hope you can help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Wow! That is some grim looking UTF-8 Support

Comment: Do you think the good isn't good? Do you have a better code? I got the code from http://www.unspecifiederror.net/2008/09/11/detecting-utf8-in-php-without-multibyte/ (thank you miek).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `utf8_decode` and check with your `detectUTF8` function if it’s still valid UTF-8.

Comment: Thank you, so simple but I didn't find out! :D It seems to work, doesn't it? http://bit.ly/wZPZm

Answer (score 2):

> [mb_detect_encoding](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php)($text, "UTF-8");

You may have to build php with [--enable-mbstring](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mbstring.installation.php) or install php-mbstring package with yum/apt, but php can help you detect multibyte string encoding.